# what exactly should be in the bytes (stream) I send to icecast via libshout2

Tags: java, audio-streaming, icecast

I'm building an icecast source in Java and I'm using libshout2 to transmit the stream.

My audio sometimes (at some large intervals) has glitches for an instant. I assume it relates to the stream rate which libshout is (should be) taking care of.

I've tried

1. transmitting the mp3 file as is (in chunks of course).
2. transmitting the frames only
3. transmitting the encoded samples (frame withought the frame header)

In all cases, over some large time period there is a glitch coming out.

So, I am wondering what could it be? What exactly should my stream sent to libshout2 should contain?

Comment: I haven't used libshout2, but you can stream to Icecast with any normal HTTP client by sending the encoded stream (such as MP3).  If you could post a sample sound of these glitches that might help identify the problem.  Are they evenly spaced?  How long are they?  And, why do you believe the stream rate is the issue and why would libshout take care of it?  If you copy data from the server directly to disk and play it back later, do you still hear the glitches?  What player are you using when you hear the glitches?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation they claim that it deals with the data and discards what is not meant to be sent, etc. This would mean, just read the file and send it in... it will handle it... well, it doesn't.

The only way that worked for me was to actually parse the file and eliminate everything except the body of the frames.